# Python Asyncio - running multiple infinite loops with different "pauses"

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio

Im trying to figure out how to run multiple infinite loops with asyncio - each loop with it's own delays:

```py
import asyncio

async def do_something(delay, message):
    await asyncio.sleep(delay)
    print(message)

def main():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.create_task(do_something(1, "delay equals 1"))  
    loop.create_task(do_something(3, "delay equals 3"))  
    loop.run_forever()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        main()
    except Exception as f:
        print('main error: ', f)
```

It returns:

```
delay equals 1
delay equals 3
```

and I would suspect it to return:

```
delay equals 1
delay equals 1
delay equals 1
delay equals 3
delay equals 1
delay equals 1
delay equals 3
```

(or similar)
How should I modify this simple routine?

---

### SOLUTION

```py
async def do_something(delay, message):
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(delay)
        print(message)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no reason why a simple task would loop forever.

Depending on what you eventually want to do, you can add a `while True:` in the async functions, or have them schedule another task at the end.

Comment: The simplest answer is always the best!